# Getting the row id then store it in session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, jqgrid

I have a problem with regards on using JQGRID.

How can I get the row number of the jqgrid then 
store it in a session.

Can anyone help me with this?  
I really don't know how will I start creating this. 
I'm new with using JQGrid and sessions

Thanks

here is my code.

```
function beforeSelect(rowid, e) {
                grid = $("#<%= jqgrid.ClientID %>");
                ItemID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'ItemID');
                var sessionItemID = '<%=Session["ItemID"] %>';
}
```

Comment: "Use it as a session"? Do you mean store it in the session?

Comment: yup, store it in session. sorry =)

Comment: I think a better approach would be to explain what you are trying to accomplish and people could help you with that problem rather then you doing a postback to store a value in the session and then having calls to retrieve that value.

Comment: i added some codes. see my updates =) thanks

Comment: i got the rowid.. but i want to use the row number.

Answer (score 0):

If your rownumber is different from rowid, you could either include an extra field to store row number, (just like you used itemId in your code). Or else, you will need to iterate through the grid to search for the particular rowid and use a counter to get rownumber:

```
function getRowNumber(rowId) {


            var rownumber= 0;
            $('#gridId tbody tr').each(function (i, n) {
                var $row = $(n);

                    if($row.find('td:eq(0)').text()==rowId)//Assuming rowid is the first column of jqgrid(index=0). Otherwise change the index appropriately

                    { rownumber=i; }

            });
           return rownumber;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The session is available on the server, while jQGrid runs on the client. This means that you can't use Javascript to directly effect the session.

What you *can* do is create an Ajax request back to the server and tell C# what you want in the session.

In your C# page...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Session["Id"] = Request.Querystring["Id"];
}
```

and then do this in your javascript once you have the Id...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Path/To/SetSession.aspx",
    data: {"Id": ItemID},
    success: function(){
        alert('Stored Ok');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Something went wrong - check the C# page for errors and check for network issues');
    }
});
```

This is an absolute minimal example - you'd want to have proper error handling in the PHP, make sure the session exists, etc...

Comment: Damnit lmao. Sorry, just finished answering another Q on PHP. The principle holds but set it in C# instead. Excuse me one sec while I edit....

Comment: Try that. Incidentally, I'm assuming you're not using Mvc in which case you'd set the session in the controller action instead of `Page_Load`